Calculating a prime number (to high approximation) using the previous two prime numbers
While doing some random stuff with prime numbers, I stumbled upon this formula which can calculate prime numbers to high approximations using the previous two prime numbers (The obvious drawback is that you have to know the previous two consecutive prime numbers).
This is what the formula looks like :
$$P_n \approx 2P_{n−1} − P_{n−2} $$
where $P_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime number.
Here are some primes I tried calculating with this formula

$n = 801854159815$
actual $P_n = 23869149137$
$P_{n-1} = 23869149137213$
$P_{n-2} = 23869149137131$
$P_n$ calculated using the formula $= 23869149137295$
Ratio of $P_n$ using the formula to actual $P_n$ = $1.000000000002681285354247213822$
deviation = $|(\text{actual }P_n) - (P_n\text{ using the formula})| = 64$



$n = 75624502104$
actual $P_n = 2065823316941$
$P_{n-1} = 2,065,823,316,937$
$P_{n-2} = 2,065,823,316,929$
$P_n$ calculated using the formula $= 2065823316945$
Ratio of $P_n$ using the formula to actual $P_n  = 1.000000000001936274011043239748$
deviation $= |(\text{actual }Pn) - (P_n\text{ using the formula})| = 4$


I searched the internet and this website to see if this formula has already been introduced, but I couldn't find it anywhere.
Can this be of any practical use? (I don't know as it relies on two consecutive prime numbers to find the next one)
​

Sorry I meant to say Pn is the nth prime number, Pn-1 is the (n-1)th prime number and Pn-2 is the (n-2)th prime number.

How do you know this isn't a coincidence?

Let me restate: this approximation assumes that the difference between the $(n-1)$st prime and the $n$th prime is the nearly the same as the difference between the $n$th prime and the $(n+1)$st prime. Then we have that $p_{n} - p_{n-1} \approx p_{n+1} - p_n$, or rearranging that $p_{n+1} \approx 2p_n - p_{n-1}$. This is approximately as good as assuming that $p_n \approx n \log n$. Is it true? No. Is this useful in practice? Not really.

@CyclotomicField I was trying to do something else with the prime numbers and matrices but I ended with this at the last.

Your first example can't be correct. How can the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime (23,869,149,137) be less than $n$ (801,854,159,815)? There must be a typo.

It should be 23,869,149,137,231 based on $P_{n-1}$ and $P_{n-2}$.

Well... I guess for some degrees of "approximation" this could be useful.  But $p_n\approx n\log n$ seems better.

Due to the density of primes, if you just said $P_n = P_{n-1}+2$ you would have very nearly almost as "good" an approximation as you showed. If you are looking at the gap to the next prime then your approximation doesn't look so good; for example you guessed $82$ when the answer is $18$.

@davidlowryduda  This does give better approximation Pn ~ nlogn. I tried it for a lot of numbers. The ratio for Pn ~ n logn (calcuated as ratio of calculated prime to actual prime) is ~0.88 to ~0.92, compared to the above formula which gives the ratio ~0.99 to ~1 always once we enter into 3 digit primes and above.

@DavidK I can't understand what you are trying to say. Can you like give an example?

I'm saying you have very small "relative errors" in your results because you are measuring error relative to the total value of the prime and primes are relatively very close together. And I did give an example of how easy it is to guess primes to about this precision if you have the previous prime, but to make it more concrete, for $n=801854159815$, suppose you estimate that $P_n$ is $23869149137215$ (I just took your $P_{n-1}$ and added $2$); I get the ratio $0.99999999999932967866\ldots$, which happens (in this case) to be closer to $1$ than your result.

Using $P_{n-1}$ gives you a huge advantage over any method that doesn't use $P_{n-1}$. All you have to do to get ratios really close to $1$ is to add an increment to $P_{n-1}$ that isn't ridiculously large.

But how would you know how much to add to $P_n-1$ for each different prime? (But as you mentioned, there might be some cases where doing this would be better than using the formula though).

Also how else would you recommend to measure error/relative errors?

It's great that you're exploring the primes. Please don't let the downvotes discourage you. But consider: people have been researching the primes for thousands of years. You're unlikely to find a simple useful pattern that others haven't found. Some important prime facts were found in relatively modern times, using calculus tools. And of course modern computers let us investigate much larger numbers than were practical in earlier times.

@PM2Ring Thanks for the support. I just wanted to share this as I thought this could be useful. I definitely don't think this is the best. Also what websites/youtube videos would you recommend to learn more about primes? I have been trying to find a good resource but not able to.

This is a good starting place: https://t5k.org/

@PM2Ring Thank you.

BTW, it's not too hard to quickly test moderate sized numbers for primality using the deterministic Miller-Rabin test. I have Python code here that goes up to 3317044064679887385961981 https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/2c9f988b5537044f5e2cdfb0bf7f1df9

@PM2Ring Thanks for the code.

Actually, say, for $p_{n-2}=90874329411493$, $p_{n-1}=90874329412297$ and $p_n=90874329411301$ we have
$$
2p_{n-1}-p_{n-2}=p_n+1800,
$$
which is rather large compared to $4$ or $64$ in your other examples.
There is a direct estimate for the $n$-th prime, namely
$$p_n\ge n\left(\ln n +\ln \ln n -1+ \dfrac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}-\dfrac{\ln^2 \ln n -6 \ln \ln n +11.508}{2 \ln^2 n}\right)$$ for all $n\ge 2$, and
$$p_n \leq n\left(\ln n +\ln \ln n -1+ \frac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}-\frac{\ln^2 \ln n -6 \ln \ln n +10.667}{2 \ln^2 n}\right)$$
for all $n\ge 46\ 254\ 381$.
Note that here is no "drawback" to know the two preceding prime numbers.

Yes you are right. I couldn't check numbers that big because online nth prime finders don't go beyond a limit. I don't think it is the best way to find primes but I think it is much more simple than the others with just basic arithmetic operations like multiplication and subtraction. I only posted it here because of its simplicity. Anyways thanks for finding an example like this.

But as you can see the ratio if still very close to 1, exactly 1.0000000000198075739503190722504. So it still calculates to a very high approximation (not really trying to prove that this method is good way to find primes, just like sharing stuff to the community).

Also I thought there might be a drawback because for larger prime number these days (found by GIMPS), I am pretty sure they are not consecutive as Mersenne primes do not produce consecutive primes. That's why I thought it could be a drawback. Thanks for confirming it is not.

For $n=801854159815$ the ratio of the upper and lower bounds is about $1.0000188$. Compare that with $1 + 1800/90874329411301$. Knowing $P_{n-1}$ still seems to give a substantial advantage. (But knowing $P_{n-2}$ doesn't seem to add much information as far as I can see.)

@DavidK I think there are sometimes where Pn-2 doesn't add much information, but lets take a very small example of Pn = 97, where if you add let's say 2 to Pn-1 i.e 89, you get 91 and the relative ratio is ~0.93 when compared to using the formula which gives relative ratio as ~0.97, but I think once you go to bigger numbers the difference between the ratios might reduce. Although I am pretty sure Pn-2 would still add at least some information to the result.

@SundararajanV Obviously the difference between consecutive primes is more than $2$ on average. I chose that as an example of an obviously bad algorithm that nevertheless performs decently for large $n$ according to your criteria. The problem with using $P_{n-2}$ is that the gaps between primes are very irregular, so if you have a small gap the next is likely to be large or if you have a large gap the next is likely to be small. Estimating the average gap between primes near $P_n$ seems like a better idea.

@DavidK ok. I will try to work on estimating the average gap.
